# Prevent users from accessing classic UI list forms

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, classic-experience, powerapps-forms

I have a custom list inside a classic team site, and i have defined it to render using new experience, as follow:-

[image]

also i customize the list forms using power app as follow:-
[image]

but if the user click on "return to classic sharepoint" >> they are able to access the classic non-customized New and Edit list forms? any idea what is going on ?

Answer (score 0):

It is the by design behavior, because the form created in PowerApps form is only work in new experience.

Comment: @Lisa Chen MSFT but i am preventing the list from rendering in classic mode,, i specify to only render it in new experience as shown in the image i provided....

Comment: There is no setting to prevent a user from entering classic mode.

Comment: @TrevorSeward but we have customized our forms using power apps ,,, so in this case users can switch to classic mode and access the non-customized forms,, there should be a way to force the list forms to only open using power app... is this correct? and what is the reason of having the 2 settings showed in the 2 screens shots i have added in my question...> thanks

Comment: There is no way to prevent a user from entering classic.

Comment: @TrevorSeward so in this case should i apply the customization i did inside the powerapp to the classic UI as well!!